# Issue when trying connect braintree drop in

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, braintree

I have added all as described here: [braintree drop in](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/ios/v4) and do pod install. But I get next errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTThreeDSecureRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libBraintreeDropIn.a(BTCardFormViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTPaymentFlowDriver", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libBraintreeDropIn.a(BTCardFormViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help with linker error - what can be done ?